# Acessing folder paths in google collab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, path, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use google collab for its tensorflow environment, but the path system looks a bit complex. What i am trying is to dynamically access the path to my train and validation folders that has cats and dogs in each folder, for classification. I am using Keras/Tensorflow, thus i am trying to access these folders from my google drive.

my cd path is currently like this: `cd "/content/drive/My Drive/data"`

[image]

Where my folder data contains train and validation folders

What i am doing is trying to simply use some data augmentation for train and validation:

```
from google.colab import files
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = 'data/train'
validation_data_dir = 'data/validation'
nb_train_samples = 1000
nb_validation_Samples = 100
epochs = 50
batch_size = 20


if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
   input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
   input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale= 1. / 255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
   train_data_dir,
   target_size=(img_width, img_height),
   batch_size=batch_size,
   class_mode='binary')


validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="binary")
```

I get the following error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/train'`

I have already mounted my drive, but i have no idea how to access my google drive folder as i would do regurarly using jupyter notebook for instance, when the folder would be in the same path as the notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First mount drive:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

And then use:
train_data_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/data/train'
validation_data_dir = '/content/drive/My Drive/data/validation'